# Is it safe to abort during "git fetch"?

Tags: git

I just started to `fetch` a large remote git repo.  Unfortunately, I only realised afterwards that due to a bad connection, it will take hours to complete.  Is it safe to issue ctrl-C (or otherwise kill the git process), and try again later on a better connection?  Or is there a risk of problems from this — my local repo getting left in a corrupt state, or something?

Comment: Afaik one of the design goals for git was, that Torvalds wanted to be able to trust his version control system. Hence the emphasis on cryptographic hashes for everything, no variables that are expanded by the VCS, etc. I can't imagine that people with this mindset would have let something as simple as a broken internet connection corrupt a repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be safe.

`git fetch` will first simply transfer new objects. After everything is downloaded it will set the remote ref to the new head commit. If you abort it during the download step it has nothing changed at to all the refs yet. Therefore everything should be fine.

Comment: Any reference or supporting evidence for that?

Comment: That is just the way git works: a ref can only point to a commit and each commit depends on its parent(s). Therefore you have to download all those commits before you are able to change a ref.

Comment: @michas: this is what I was guessing/hoping too, but it would be really nice to have a pointer to something in the manual or similar that would confirm it.  (p.s. I was not the downvoter.)

Comment: You have only two options. Either understand the concepts as I pointed out above or read the actual [implementation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/fetch.c#L877).

Comment: I understand the concepts, but abstractions are often leaky, and a high-level outline can make a process sound more robust than actually it is.  So “understand the concepts” is not something one can rely on.  Thank you for the link to the source, though — it would have been nice if there were a more accessible reference for this point (e.g. in the manual or the git book), but in lieu of that, the source is something.